# TimerTask stops running after midnight

Tags: java, raspberry-pi4

I have a small part of the program that has a timer to take a picture using a usb webcamera through the command line (fswebcam) every 15 minutes.

The code is like this:

```
public static final String HOME_DIR = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/";
public static final String PGP_DIR = HOME_DIR + "PGP/";

public static final String COLLECTION_DATA_DIR = PGP_DIR + "collectionData/";
public static final String SENSOR_CALIBRATION_DATA = PGP_DIR + "sensorCalibration/";
public static final String PICTURE_DIR = PGP_DIR + "pictures/";
public static final String ALARM_DIR = PGP_DIR + "alarms/";
private class PictureTakerTask extends TimerTask{
        Timer t;
        public void start(){
            if(t != null){
                t.cancel();
                t.purge();
                t = null;
                this.cancel();
            }
            t = new Timer(true);
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1000 * 60 * 15); //takes a picture every 15 minutes
        }

        public void stop(){
            if(running) return;
            if(t != null){
                t.cancel();
                t.purge();
                t = null;
            }
            this.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            String filename = getPictureFilename();
            if(filename == null) return;
            Process p;
            try {
                CommIO.printLog("Taking a picture");
                String file;
                light.setGreenPWM(80);
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner -S 1 " + filename);
                p.waitFor();
                System.out.println ("picture taken with exit value: " + p.exitValue());
                p.destroy();
                light.setGreenPWM(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                light.setGreenPWM(0);
            }
        }

        private String getPictureFilename(){
            //make folder if it doesn't exist already
            SimpleDateFormat justDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
            String date = justDate.format(new Date());
            String s = PICTURE_DIR + date + "/";
            File picDir = new File(s);
            if(!picDir.exists()){
                if(picDir.mkdir()){
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Couldn't make picture directory: " + s, ButtonType.OK);
                }
            }
            //find an unused filename
            String picFileName = s + "plant_01.jpg";
            File tempFile = new File(picFileName);
            int i = 1;
            while (tempFile.exists()) { //finds the next nonexistent name for data spreadsheet
                String num = i < 10 ? "0" + i : "" + i;
                picFileName = s + "plant_" + num + ".jpg";
                i++;
                tempFile = new File(picFileName);
                if(i > 10000) break;
            }
            return picFileName;
        }
    }
```

The thread starts and works fine, until midnight exactly. It will fail to take pictures the next day. I can't figure out for the life of me why it stops. If I stop and restart the task it will work fine again. If I even take a picture through the terminal outside the program it will work fine again. It just will quit taking pictures by the next day. It even creates the next day's folder, just no pictures. No error messages (that I can find).

Does anybody have any ideas or experience with this? Before you say it, no I can't use motion or Cron because I need to be synchronized with the "light" object in the run() function.

Comment: *…or Cron because I need to be synchronized with the "light" object in the run() function.* Why, as it happens, would cron have a problem with that? You could just set your light in the cron script. Another question: are you always getting an exit code of zero?

Comment: What exactly is `PICTURE_DIR`?

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: util.Date. Also g00se, the "light" in question is actually tied to a serial port and being communicated frequently (about once a second) in a separate timer (multiple timers actually) in the same program. I don't want to deal with the extra problem of resource/synchronization conflicts via separate programs, the separate timers are enough headache.

Comment: @BasilBourque edited question to include directories. simplifies to "pihome"/PGP/pictures

Comment: I don't suspect the timer, unless the exception is leaked to the timer thread causing the timer stop
1. Do you see the log for every 15 min
2. Take thread dump to see in case the image capture process hangs (command: jstack <PID>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Simple mistake, actually:

```
if(picDir.mkdir()){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Couldn't make picture directory: " + s, ButtonType.OK);
}
```

Forgot the negation of condition. I usually run the program more than once in a day to check other changes, so it makes the folder on the first time, crashes the thread, and runs fine the next couple times I start the program. But when the next day comes around, it makes an Alert and throws a tantrum because it's not on the FX thread. It was difficult to notice because I forgot to actually even show the Alert.

I love java-fx, but it can be so finicky sometimes. Fixed by adding negation, and putting the alert into a Platform.runLater Runnable.

Comment: That was my guess. By the way, your code has more room for improvement. I started writing example code, but is too much of a tangent to post here. Issues include: (a) You are using terrible date-time  classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. (b) `TimerTask` & `Timer` were years ago supplanted by the Executors framework. (c) You are using old file I/O classes that were years ago supplanted by NIO.2. (d) Some minor issues include naming a method with `get…` that does much more than access a field. You formatting of sequence should be 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and set the time to 12:00:01am at 11:59:59pm. I'm not sure if that would fix it. A while loop could work.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great approach. For one, unless you set the clock back at some point, the system clock will precess by 2 seconds a day.